# If you publish something, do people have to cite you by your surname?

Tags: citations

If an author strongly wished to be referred to in other works by his or her given name, is there a way that the convention of referencing an author by last name could be broken?

Answer (score 2):

Poet e e cummings and singer k.d. lang are both referenced in all lowercase letters. Singer Prince famously went by an unpronounceable symbol for a few years (which many wrote as The Artist Formerly Known As Prince, or TAFKAP). Many artists go by one name: singers Adele, Cher, Madonna; cartoonist Herblock; French writer Molière; British writer Saki.

If you want to publish under Jacob (or another first name), you certainly can, but if it's a common name, it might be difficult to market your work.

Now, if what you want is to go normally by "Jacob Jones" but for the *New York Times* to write in a review "The new book by Jacob Jones came out this week. This is the third novel Jacob has written in the last three years," then no, you can't force publications to break their house style just for you and reference you as "Jacob" rather than "Mr. Jones." Or rather, you can try, but you'll come across as a special snowflake, and earn a certain amount of critical derision.

Comment: *Poet e e cummings and singer k.d. lang are both referenced in all lowercase letters.* – Says who? [This copy editor](http://www.theslot.com/caps.html) and I disagee. Spelling rules win over personal quirks.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes, you are obliquely underlining my final point: You can *try* to get people to refer to you in a special way, but it's difficult to force them. The *NYT* refers to "Adele," no courtesy title, but "K.D. Lang," capitalized normally. One of my clients will always refer to the sportswear company as *adidas*, even at the beginning of a sentence. I would say "house rules win overall." Some places will allow the quirks and some won't. Prince freely distributed a font with his name-glyph to allow (and encourage) people to indulge him.